# Put a window behind desktop icons

Tags: c++, c, winapi

currently I've this but it doesn't put my window behind the desktop

```
SetWindowPos(hWnd,HWND_BOTTOM,0,0,SCREEN_WIDTH,SCREEN_HEIGHT,SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
ShowWindow(hWnd,SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE);
```

i want to put my window behind every window even the taskbar and desktop icons window
please help me how can i do this 
thanks in advance

Comment: You simply can't, the Windows desktop isn't a window.

Comment: desktop icons isn't part of some window ? i've seen some programs do it

Comment: No, you haven't. You might have seen other programs **draw** on the desktop, but you didn't see them put a **window** behind it. They're not the same thing at all. It's the difference between drawing a picture of your car on the window of a house and actually parking your car in the living room. They're not the same, right?

Comment: hmm, i used spy++ and found it's 'FolderView' window behind which i want to put my window i'm trying to do that thanks

Comment: spy++ says you can make FolderView your parent and then draw on it somehow, i dont know, i'll just make taskbar on top with timer,it's ok for me not to put my window behind desktop icons

Comment: what actually you want to do?

Comment: draw things behind desktop icons,now i managed to put taskbar on top of my window so it's umm solved

Comment: Well...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34952967/drawing-to-the-desktop-via-injection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Desktop is a ListView control, and the desktop icons are its list items.  Top-level windows can be made children of that ListView window, but it is impossible to place a child window between the ListView's background and its list items.  The only way to make anything appear behind the items is to draw directly on the ListView's background, such as by subclassing it to intercept its `WM_ERASEBKGND` and `WM_PAINT` messages.